# PyInstaller - when opening cant find _tkinter Module (required by PySimpleGui)

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

I have a quesetion. I made a Python App and wanted to distribute this to friends.

I used PySimpleGui for the GUI and when I open the .py App with Python it works fine. But when I package it with PyInstaller and then open it I get this message:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Dev/application/dist/APPLICATION                                                                                         1 ✘  14:57:29 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stamp.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "PySimpleGUI/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 111, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
[53336] Failed to execute script 'APPLICATION' due to unhandled exception!
```

Im using MacOS with Big Sur 11.5, Python 3.9.6 (with Pyenv) and PyInstaller 4.5.1.

I already tried troubleshooting with:

- Reinstalling PySimpleGui
- Reinstalling tkinter
- use "hidden imports" for both
- ...

but nothing works...

Can I bundle tkinter with the application?

Comment: Look at what the documentation has to say about "hidden imports".

Comment: I already tried to import tkinter over hiddenimports, its not working, same error